# vba code to select only visible cells in specific column except heading

Tags: excel, vba

I need code to select only visible cells in a specific column except the heading.

This is what I tried:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

But the above code will select the entire column except the heading. I need it to only select a specific column (use column D for your answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will select all visible cells with data in column D, except header and  last visible cell with data:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectVisibleInColD()
    Dim lRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet

        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

        If lRow < 3 Then Exit Sub

        .Cells(1, 4).Offset(1, 0).Resize(lRow - 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout: I was going to upvote yours... your answers always work because you're explicit with everything

Comment: Compile Error: invalid or unqualified reference... Its because of .Rows and. Columns I guess... I tried by removing dot but selecting all visible cells... Please help me What to do?

Comment: That's ok.. Your code is shorter and I like it and hence I deleted mine ;)

Comment: @SudarshanKShetty: please update your question with all relevant code, including the line with the error (make sure to include the first and 3rd line: `With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(4)` and `End With`)

Comment: There was something bothering me about this code... I was wondering as to why did I use LastRow and then it dawned upon me... Now I know what :D It is the `UsedRange` :) More about `Usedrange` [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: Awesome dude... Thank you so much... Its working...One problem its selecting entire column... Can you code it only for the visible cells which contains data less one last cell...

Comment: @SudarshanKShetty: Exactly my thoughts and hence you need to find the last row as shown in my answer

Comment: There you go: @SiddharthRout's answer provides the fix; I'll update mine as well

Comment: As we are excluding the heading... I also want to exclude the last cell which is visible and contains data... I'm sorry I'm asking a lot of follow up questions

Comment: If you think about it carefully, you will get the answer to your question ;)  @SudarshanKShetty

Comment: Ok, I updated it so it selects all visible cells in col D except for the 1st row and the last visible cell with data

Comment: Sorry I changed your code as it was not compiling. Also took care of the scenario where there was data only till Cell A2 :) Feel free to roll back the changes if you want to...

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying? This will select all visible cells **till the last row** in column A except the header:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~>  I also want to exclude the last cell which is visible and contains data
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1 

        If lRow < 3 Then Exit Sub

        Debug.Print Intersect( _
                              .Range("A2:A" & lRow), _
                              .Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                              ).Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: works well (you may want to update "until last row - 1")