# How can I un-hide hidden rows in a table in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I made a code to hide some rows using *.hidden = True* that I don't need to show to make some checks, but I after that I want to show all the data again, so I made this code:

```
Sub show_hidden_cells()
Dim line As Range
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("Tb_Data[Date]")

For Each line In rng
    If line.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) = False Then
        line.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next line
End Sub
```

My data has 50.000 rows and my computer it's not really fast, so I don't want to check every cell if is visible, instead of that I want to select only the hidden cells.

EDIT.
Thanks to @Rory and @Flephal who helped me my code now is:

```
Sub show_hidden_cells()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("Tb_Data[Date]")
rng.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vba code to select only visible cells in specific column except heading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425791/vba-code-to-select-only-visible-cells-in-specific-column-except-heading)

Comment: Why not just use `rng.EntireRow.Hidden = False` without the loop?

Comment: Why test the rows when you want to unhide all the data in the specified range? Just use rng.EntireRow.Hidden = False

Comment: @KobyDouek I don't understand how this post can help me. I already know how to select only the visible cells (using .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) my problem is the opposite and I don't see in the post some way to help me, Would you please highlight me where in the post is the code I need?

Comment: Rory and Flephal I didn't know I can use this and it works as I want, thanks so much. :D